# can python understand a human language?

Tags: human-language

I started learning python some months ago.
However, I came accRoss a job online and my client wanted me to write a web application to analyse stories and get features like title, characters, proverbs, morals and songs.
I achieved this through labeling and indexing.

But he further stated that he wanted the code to have the ability to understand the story and generate morals and some other things by itself without labelling the moral to fetch locally in the code.

The stories are in a Nigerian language and I don't know if this is possible.
Please is this possible?

Comment: You're going into machine learning territory here, and that's a deep rabbit hole. Almost surely *possible*, but if no one's done it before you might need to start breaking new ground.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is it achievable in python? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, yes. You won't be able to get anyone to write a guide for you here though. This is a huge question. You'll need to do a ton of research first.